# Send data to a user control inside another user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

### What I need

I need for the Comments UC to make a collection of all the latest comments bound to the repeater in, for example, `List<CommentInfo>` and send it to `Comment` UC through `DataRef` property so I can display each comment.

I've tried to make a collection inside `Comments_ItemDataBound`, but I have no way of knowing when I've been through all the data since `comments.Items.Count` doesn't have a total item count before all the comments are being data bound.

```
int count = 1;
List<CommentInfo> commentsList = new List<CommentInfo>();
protected void comments_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        cil.Add(new CommentInfo
        {
            username = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "username").ToString()
            ...
        });

        // comments.Items.Count here is 0, on next data bound will be 1 and count will be 2
        if (comments.Items.Count == 5)
        {
            var comment = e.Item.FindControl("comment1") as Comment;
            comment.DataRef = commentsList;
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

The problem this question is asking is how to make a `List<CommentInfo>` collection of all the comments to pass them to `DataRef` property.

---

`Comments` User Control has a repeater for showing the latest comments.
The repeater's `DataSource` is from SQL Server.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="comments" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Comments_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <uc1:Comment ID="comment1" runat="server" />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

`Comment` UC is to show one comment from the collection of comments it receives from `Comments`'s repeater through public property `DataRef` type of `Object` which I will cast to any class I need before I send it to `Comment` UC, at least that's my idea.

```
<div class="comment" id="<%= DataRef.comment_id %>">
    <a class="comment-link" href="/<%= DataRef.friendly_url %>">
    Written by: <strong><%= DataRef.username %></strong>, <%= DataRef.comment_date %></em>
    <%= DataRef.comment_text %></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What type is `Comment.DataRef` declared as? What is the type you are binding to your repeater? Why can't you simply change one to match the other?

Comment: Comment.DataRef is of type Object. SqlDataReader is the type I am binding to the repeater. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to ask for the data as he iterate the repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="comments" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>    
        <uc1:Comment ID="comment1" runat="server" 
               DataRef="<%#GetMyReference(Container.DataItem)%>" />        
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and on code behind

```
public object GetMyReference(object oItem)
{
     // I am not sure what you wish to return here...
     // or you may want to full return the oItem, I am not sure
     //   this is an example
     return DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "yourDataItem");
}
```

Note that the `DataRef` is a public value on your user control.

similar answers : [Add a list of self created web user controls to a listview in codebehind fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522019/add-a-list-of-self-created-web-user-controls-to-a-listview-in-codebehind-fails/3522184#3522184)
and [Virtual Listview for ASP.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981084/virtual-listview-for-asp-net/10981815#10981815)

Comment: I didn't explain it well so I updated the question.

Comment: @Codesmell try to understand and do what I have suggest you here. Its helps you solve your problem ( I read your update, and the answer is the same)...

Comment: My mistake. I didn't understand at first. Thought it worked differently so I read the MSDN docs again and got it working, but it's not what I need. I was so focused on explaining what I want and I forgot to explicitly said what I want. I apologize for that, so I edited the question again.